# Can you help me about leaflet map ? it is like a broken puzzle [react-leaflet]

Tags: react-leaflet

I can't style [react-leaflet] map and it is showing me several  tags on another  points, my map is like broken puzzle and when I scroll it this  tags position is changing, I did for it container with width and height, I have also overflow: hidden for that container, but I have trouble with view of map.[Problem what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSjbb.jpg)

Comment: This issue has been discussed million times in SO. If you search more carefully you will find the solution in many posts

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to put this link in the head of your html file.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
       integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
       crossorigin=""/>
```

And add this script tag right after that link.

```html
     <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
       integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
       crossorigin=""></script>
```

This should fix your problem... but if you still can not see the map, go to your css stylesheet and add whatever height you want to .leaflet-container class.